# Can anyone translate the writing on the back of this postcard from 1936?

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

[image]

It is a postcard from 1936, with Hitler shaking hands with a lady with the military behind them.

Comment: A cropped flatbed scan at higher resolution might be helpful. A bit of context (family heirloom?) might help to decipher the name in the address.

Answer (score 38):

This is a German [Kurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) handwriting. When transcribing all letters to a Kurrent font we read:

[image]

which says:

> die besten Grüße vom Reichsparteitag 1936 sendet Franz.
>    *best regards from the Nuremberg Rally 1936 sends Franz*

Comment: Very good idea to present the handwriting in Kurrent font, too!

Comment: Yeah it helps immensely for direct comparison.

Comment: It's remarkable that you can read a writing system where _n_, _e_, _m_ and _u_ all basically just merge into a sawtooth line...

Comment: ...it puzzles myself sometimes ;) I had to learn Kurrent at school (art lessons) and did some practise later to be able to read correspondence of my grandparents. If you had to write it you will actually see the subtle differences in the letters but if it was a sloppy handwriting it may end in wild guessing rather than reading.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Ein instead of Die in the beginning?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins it might be irritating that the “e” looks almost like “n” in that writing, however, it’s used consistently throughout the entire text. In short, no, it’s a “Die” at the beginning.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Besides, "Ein besten Grüße" would be gramatically wrong.

Comment: @mkrieger1 of course it would. But it could as well be a mistype/spelling error.

Comment: @Holger, indeed, in other places this 'n' means 'e' as well. Apparently you're right.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins in the picture of this answer, there is a small visual difference between `n` and `e` in the height of the lower left starting point of the diagonal line. Of course, the real handwriting on the postcard is less clear.

Comment: @Holger Wow, indeed so. In Russian those two are different letters as well. Handwritten Russian can be as hard to decypher as this Kurrent sometimes. Especially doctor's prescriptions. :)

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins I suppose, doctor’s prescriptions are unreadable all over the world…

Answer (score 18):

And additional to Takkat's answer the postal address reads:

> Frau Karl M [...] rmann
>
> in Kalkar Kr. Kleve
>   Niederrhein

"Kr." is the abbreviation for "Kreis" which is the administrative district.
The surname is hard to read because of the postmark.
"Karl" is of course a male first name, but 1936 it was quite usual to use the first name of the husband in mailing addresses and similar.

[image]